# MakeIndex in TexMaker with auxiliary files in subfolder

Tags: texmaker, indexing, imakeidx

I have the TexMaker option to put output in a "build" subfolder checked. So I have my idx file in the folder "build". When I run MakeIndex I get `Input index file book.idx not found. Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]` Then if I go and configure MakeIndex as: `makeindex build/%.idx` I get

```
`Scanning input file build/libro.idx...
done (0 entries accepted, 33 rejected). Nothing written in build/book.ind. 
Transcript written in build/book.ilg.`
```

The .tex file:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
test\index{test}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

The .idx file contains:

```
\indexentry{test}{1}
```

But even though the .idx file is generated I don't see the index in the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I have duplicated your set up and files and they work fine if you use the expected compile sequence.

You need to run `pdflatex` first to generate the .idx file.  Then you need to run `makeindex` to create the needed .aux file.  And finally you need to run `pdflatex` again to get the PDF file.  Note it will located in the build directory.

The shortcuts which work very smoothly is to have your main .tex file in the open TeXmaker window.  Then press F6, wait for compile to complete.  Then press F12 to run `makeindex`. Wait for the index to complete.  Now run F6 again to rerun `pdflatex`.  Wait.  Finally run F7 to view the PDF file.

Comment: That will certainly work, but then you are losing the convenience that `imakeidx` offers - that simply running `pdflatex` will do all of this for you automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this issue by moving the `.idx` file **out of the build folder** and compiling again. It is a bit inconvenient because you have to keep doing that when you want to update the index page – as new versions of such file will still be created inside `./build/` – but it is the only way I have got it working.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!